# How to perform bootstrapping to a diagnostic test in R?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am analysing the accuracy of two diagnostics tests that detect if an individual has disease ("1") or no disease ("0") against a ground truth (gold standard). I want to calculate sensitivity, specificity and likelihood ratios with 95% Confidence Intervals. However, I need to do the analysis with bootstrapping and I haven't been able to manage to do it so far. Would deeply appreciate an example with the following data set or suggestions for which package to use and which functions to code.

this is a fragment of my database

[Link for Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfVwJ.png)

I have already managed to calculate sensitivity, specificity and likelihood ratios with CI using the acc.1test. However, I need to apply bootstrapping to this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of bootstraping using the R package [rsample](https://tidymodels.github.io/rsample/index.html). There are many other possibilities like [boot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf), [bootstrap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/bootstrap.pdf) or manual coding but I like this approach since it's very flexible. First of all I load the packages

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rsample)
library(yardstick)
#> For binary classification, the first factor level is assumed to be the event.
#> Set the global option `yardstick.event_first` to `FALSE` to change this.
```

That warning means that we need to set `options(yardstick.event_first = FALSE)` since the first factor level for `gold_std`, `test1` and `test2` is 0.

```r
options(yardstick.event_first = FALSE)
```

Then i load the data

```r
data <- tibble(
  ID = 1:25, 
  gold_std = factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), 
  test_1 = factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)), 
  test_2 = factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
)
```

The confusion matrix is:

```r
table(select(data, gold_std, test_1))
#>         test_1
#> gold_std 0 1
#>        0 8 7
#>        1 1 9
```

which means that the sensitivity is equal to 9 / (9 + 1) and specificity is equal to 8 / (7 + 8). Indeed

```r
sens(data, truth = gold_std, estimate = test_1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 sens    binary           0.9
```

and

```r
spec(data, truth = gold_std, estimate = test_1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 spec    binary         0.533
```

The functions `sens` e `spec` are defined in the R package `yardstick`. I can use the R package `rsample` to create 30 bootstrap replicates of the data:

```r
set.seed(1)
bootstrap_data <- bootstraps(data, times = 30)
```

and this is the result

```r
bootstrap_data
#> # Bootstrap sampling 
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>    splits          id         
#>    <list>          <chr>      
#>  1 <split [25/9]>  Bootstrap01
#>  2 <split [25/13]> Bootstrap02
#>  3 <split [25/11]> Bootstrap03
#>  4 <split [25/7]>  Bootstrap04
#>  5 <split [25/10]> Bootstrap05
#>  6 <split [25/10]> Bootstrap06
#>  7 <split [25/8]>  Bootstrap07
#>  8 <split [25/7]>  Bootstrap08
#>  9 <split [25/9]>  Bootstrap09
#> 10 <split [25/7]>  Bootstrap10
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

`bootstrap_data` is a new dataframe with 30 rows (as many as the number of boostrap replications) and 2 columns: `splits` e `id`. The column `splits` records the number of observations excluded from each bootstrap replicate while `id` is simply and id column. For example in the first replicate of the bootstrap samples 9 observations were excluded. Moreover we can use the function `analysis` to retrive the observations sampled in each bootrstrap replicate. This is a more efficient way to store the indexes of a bootstrap sampling.

Now I can define two function which take as input a split object and return the estimate of sensitivity and specificity for that boostrap sample.

```r
bootstrap_sens <- function(splits) {
  x <- analysis(splits)
  sens(x, truth = gold_std, estimate = test_1)$.estimate
}

bootstrap_spec <- function(splits) {
  x <- analysis(splits)
  spec(x, truth = gold_std, estimate = test_1)$.estimate
}
```

I use the notation `$.estimate` since I need just the estimate of sensitivity and specificity (and you can see from the output at the beginning that they return a dataframe). I can apply these functions to the bootstrap replicates using `map_dbl` (since the output of both functions is an object of type double) and this is the result:

```r
bootstrap_data <- bootstrap_data %>% 
  mutate(
    sens = map_dbl(splits, bootstrap_sens), 
    spec = map_dbl(splits, bootstrap_spec)
  )
bootstrap_data
#> # Bootstrap sampling 
#> # A tibble: 30 x 4
#>    splits          id           sens  spec
#>  * <list>          <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 <split [25/9]>  Bootstrap01 0.727 0.571
#>  2 <split [25/13]> Bootstrap02 1     0.471
#>  3 <split [25/11]> Bootstrap03 1     0.312
#>  4 <split [25/7]>  Bootstrap04 0.9   0.533
#>  5 <split [25/10]> Bootstrap05 0.8   0.533
#>  6 <split [25/10]> Bootstrap06 1     0.364
#>  7 <split [25/8]>  Bootstrap07 0.9   0.6  
#>  8 <split [25/7]>  Bootstrap08 1     0.533
#>  9 <split [25/9]>  Bootstrap09 0.667 0.625
#> 10 <split [25/7]>  Bootstrap10 0.667 0.75 
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can use the same approach for `test_2`. I'm not sure what you mean by `likelihood ratios` but you can define your own function to evalute it and apply it in the same way as `bootstrap_sens` or `bootstrap_spec`. You can find much more details about rsample at the package website.